# How do I switch language in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

I am playing with a few programming languages within Visual Studio Code.  My initial language is Python, and then I added Go in there within their own respective folders.  When I run the Go file, it tries to interpret with Python, which obviously would fail.

1. Could I have different languages within the same project and separate them by different interpreter?
2. How do I point one folder to run with Python, the other to run with Go?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you reviewed [debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging) practices and setting up configurations?  https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go

Comment: change the launch configuration in the Debug/Run sidebar or create a Go one

Comment: Thanks y'all, the debugging.md link was helpful.  I figured out the issue.  I had to install the latest GO package, and then modify the launch.json file to include GO type.

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten it to work.  The Configuration settings control what you are building.  It is set within the launch.json file, and you can have different languages with the same project and run them in different interpreter/compiler.

This is what I have in my launch.json.

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "GO: Launch",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "auto",
        "program": "${fileDirname}",
        "env": {},
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }

]
```